# Iterating over dictionary or its items

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

What's a better practice and what's faster:

- iterating over dictionary (practically by its keys):
  `for key in dictionary: ...`
- or iterating over its items:
  `for key, value in dictionary.items(): ...`?

Using `dict.items()` seems to be a more clean way to iterate over a dictionary, but isn't it slower because of creating another object (`dict.items`) (I suppose it's negligible, but I had to ask)? Or maybe it's already done with initializing the dictionary?
Also, in the first way, accessing a value by its key shouldn't affect the efficiency because the operation is *O(1)*.

Comment: `.items()` returns a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), so its performance impact is indeed negligible.

Comment: IIRC iterating over the dictionary is also just a shorthand for `iter(dict.keys())`, which is also a view object. So performance should be pretty much the same anyways, with a view object being used no mater how you iterate.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to the view objects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run some tests.

```py
from time import perf_counter

i = {i: 10 for i in range(10**7)}

def t1():
    p1 = perf_counter()
    for key in i:
        i[key]
    print("key in i:",perf_counter() - p1)

def t2():
    p1 = perf_counter()
    for key, value in i.items():
        value
    print("key, value in i.items()", perf_counter() - p1)

t1()
t2()
```

### OUTPUT

```
key in i: 0.2863648850000118
key, value in i.items() 0.19483049799998753
```

---

As you can see, iterating with the 'items' method is significantly faster. That's because when we use `key in dict`, we iterate through keys while ignoring value; value should be taken directly from the dictionary using `dict[x]` or `dict.get(x)` which is by default, do all hash table steps:

- calls hash function with your attribute x
- searches into the hash table's array which is hidden by default and we can't see it because it's implementation detail
- if there are any collisions, they should be solved

However, when we use items, it iterates through the dictionary and collects keys with the values, so we do not need to perform all of the hash table steps for each item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, even though it's an *O(1)* operation, it still has some effect on the performance.

Comment: Yes, as the worst-case scenario is a "O(N)" and it's not necessarily "O(1)".

Comment: Ye, you right, I somehow forgot about the worst case. Thanks!